# UI-Grid - Row height and whitespace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid, row-height

I'm trying to minimize the whitespace that is used when you use an expandable row template. I am using the component UI-grid in AngularJS.

Here is a plunker:
[Code preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNzJBSAwn8GgAAdAgyB1?p=preview)

As you can see in the plunker, I created a expandable row template with a textarea inside it. When you open a row on the main grid you'll see that there is no whitespace left because I added some css to remove the whitespace.

```
.expandableRow{
  height:auto !important;
}
```

This class is auto generated when the view is loaded by ui-grid.

The no whitespace is correct but the problem is the that the '(+)' plus sign to open a row doesn't resize with the height of the textarea.

This is how it looks now:

```
(+) Notification Date     | Title
-----------------------------------
    (-) 12/01/2016        | Test
        Here is a message
        01/01/2017        | test2
        07/01/2017        | Test3
    (+)
    (+)
```

This is how it should look:

```
(+) Notification Date     | Title
-----------------------------------
    (-) 12/01/2016        | Test
        Here is a message
    (+) 01/01/2017        | test2
    (+) 07/01/2017        | Test3
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: Have you tried using `grid.options.expandableRowHeight`? This let's you define a fixed height but won't work with resizing the `textarea`

Comment: The textarea doesn't need any resizing, the row needs to be resized to the textarea height. But yeah, i've tried that but didn't work.

Comment: I was able to set `expandableRowHeight` and have the extra white space disappear. Here is your updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/akaIw9?p=preview)

Comment: Hello, yes in that way it is working but the textarea is not a static value, it always change(it is kind of mailing system where a user can check the history of the messages). And the textarea is auto resizing not cropping